# Request limited amount of endpoints at once

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I tried to write a function that requests only limited amount of mock endpoints at one time. As soon as one request is resolved, the next one is fetching.
Here is my code:

```js
const requestQueue = (endpoints, callback, limit = 3) => {
    while (endpoints.length > 0) {
        if (limit > 0) {
            const slice = endpoints.splice(0, limit)
            for (const endpoint of slice) {
                limit--
                fetchMock(endpoint)
                    .then(data => callback(data))
                    .catch(err => callback(err))
                    .finally(() => limit++)
            }
        }
    }
}

function fetchMock(endpoint) {
    return Promise.resolve(endpoint)
}

requestQueue([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], data => console.log(data))
```

It goes in infinite loop and crashes. What am I missing or misunderstaning? Help please.

Comment: You're incrementing a variable inside an asynchronous code block. That happens at **some indeterminate time in the future**, not as you'd expect here on an immediate basis.

Comment: I'd suggest using a timer here rather than spinning *hard* inside a `while` loop. Give this async code time to settle.

Comment: @tadman but when promise resolves, limit will be incremented right? And while is not going anywhere, it's spinning and checking the limit (or not cause it doesn't work ;( )

Comment: FYI: You could also use a Semaphore e.g. using [async-mutex](https://github.com/DirtyHairy/async-mutex) which does not increase your CPU utilization to the max. It's also open source, if you're interested in their implementation.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me here. This is spinning **HARD**, as in that loop is running continuously, unrelentingly, using 100% CPU while basically doing nothing. You'll need to chill out. Use a time interval of 100ms or so, poll frequently, but not *continuously*. You're the kid in the back of the car yelling "Arewethereyet?" endlessly. Don't be that.

Comment: In other words: A) Make a poll function that checks the current situation and initiates any `fetchMock` calls that seem necessary. B) Schedule this poll using `setInterval()`. C) When the task is complete, cancel your timer.

Comment: @Yousaf I thought it is clear in code that as soon as one request is resolved, the next one is fetching. Sorry for confusing, added to the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for infinite loop is `limit` variable getting decremented to zero inside the `for of` loop; as a result, the `while` loop's condition `endpoints.length > 0` is never evaluated as `false`.

The `endpoints.length` is always greater than zero because you don't let the loop enter the `if` block after the first iteration. After the first iteration, `limit` is zero, so `limit > 0` is not `true` after the first iteration. As a result, the loop is stuck in an infinite cycle.

Now you might say: *"But I have increment the `limit` inside the `finally` callback, so `limit` is not always zero"*.

For `limit` to get incremented, the callback function of `finally` has to be executed BUT that never happens because the asynchronous code (*callbacks of `then`, `catch`, and `finally` are invoked asynchronously*) is executed *after* synchronous code execution ends BUT in your case, **synchronous code execution never ends** because it is stuck in the `while` loop. You didn't give `finally` callback a chance to get executed.

As a matter of fact, none of the promise callbacks are invoked in your code because synchronous code execution has to end for them to be invoked and you are hoping to end the synchronous code execution after asynchronous callbacks are invoked. Your code is stuck in a deadlock.

---

As you want to initiate the request to another endpoint as soon as any of the initially started requests are completed, following code shows this in action:

```js
let offset = 0;

function makeRequest(endpoints, callback) {
  console.log('fetching endpoint ' + endpoints[offset]);
  fetchMock(endpoints[offset++])
    .then(callback)
    .catch(callback)
    .finally(() => {
      if (offset < endpoints.length) {
        requestQueue(endpoints, callback);
      }
    });
}

const requestQueue = (endpoints, callback, limit = 3) => {
  if (offset >= endpoints.length) {
    return;
  }

  if (offset === 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      makeRequest(endpoints, callback);
    }
  } else {
    makeRequest(endpoints, callback);
  }
};

function fetchMock(endpoint) {
  // random delay between 1 to 4 seconds
  const randomDelay = (Math.random() * (5 - 1) + 1) * 1000;
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, randomDelay, endpoint));
}

requestQueue([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], data => console.log(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I need to limit count of fetching functions to the given limit. So if I have [1,2,3,4,5] and limit is 3, it goes [1,2,3] and as soon as one of them is resolved, the next (4) is fetching. And then as soon as 2 or 3 or 4 or some of them are resolved the next ones are fetching till we get the limit of amount of fetching functions. Only three items of the array are fetching at one time. Anyway thanks for the explanation why my code doesn't work

Comment: Code updated to match your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all` to run a slice items simultaneously in a batch:

```js
const requestQueue = async (endpoints, callback, limit = 3, offset = 0) => {

    const slice = endpoints.slice(offset, offset + limit);

    if(!slice.length){
        return;        
    }

    // map slice into fetchMock calls and await the batch
    await Promise.all(slice.map(endpoint => fetchMock(endpoint).then(callback).catch(callback)));

    // delay between slices, remove if not needed
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    
    // run the next slice
    return requestQueue(endpoints, callback, limit, offset += limit);
}

function fetchMock(endpoint) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(endpoint), Math.random()*1000));
}

requestQueue([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], data => console.log(data))
```